# Security: Critical backend outside of wordpress

Tags: security, server

For starters, apologies for my miserable knowledge of web development.

I have been developing a simple website for my startup and have encountered some security concerns. Knowing my limited knowledge and all the possible vulnerabilities related to wordpress and human error, I wanted to implement simple backend operations on an external server/service.

This would be ideal as my added-value as a company will be on my database and the algorithm that processes it. As such, I was hoping I could decouple these from any wordpress-related problems.

Any idea/suggestion of how I could implement this as safely as possible, or any problems I might encounter?

Thanks ;)

Answer (score 0):

My security knowledge of Wordpress is not that deep, but I believe this might help you a bit:
- First find the vulnerabilities, once you know which one exists, research and find out how to fix it specifically.

To find:
- The WordFence Plugin is very good for this.
- https://forum.fsocietybrasil.org/topic/992-wordpress-scan-vulnerabilities-and-malwares/ Here is a list of sites to scan the failing of your wp
- https://sitecheck.sucuri.net Here you can scan if there is a virus on your site (often plugins bring viruses)
Look for ebooks on the internet, I only have Portuguese, I do not think they will help you much the ones I have
- Firefox's noscript Addon makes an excellent scan as well.